# SVN repository - user premissions issue

Tags: debian, subversion

I have created the repository long time ago when I was the only user. Now I need to add another user, so I created a usergroup where I added the both users and did the following:

```
chmod -R user1:usergroup svnrepo/*
chown -R 0770 svnrepo/*
```

Now we all have the ability to update and commit but the problem is that when one of us commits, it aparently changes the owner of `svnrepo/db/current` (to the user who committed) and the other person loses access to the repo, until I manually set the proper owner again.

Do you have an idea how to fix that? It is extremely annoying...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is a recommended way to share access to a SVN repository. You're using the `file:///` protocol to access the repo and it's generally discouraged to do it this way. See this StackOverflow Q&A titled: [svn repository on Windows network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289850/svn-repository-on-windows-network-share).

From the [TortoiseSVN documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share)

> file:// access is intended for local, single-user access only,
>   particularly testing and debugging. When you want to share the
>   repository you really need to set up a proper server, and it is not
>   nearly as difficult as you might think. Read [the section called
>   “Accessing the Repository”](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup.html) for guidelines on choosing and setting up a
>   server.

This same [sentiment is echoed in the SVN Bean Book as well](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html).

> Do not be seduced by the simple idea of having all of your users
>   access a repository directly via file:// URLs. Even if the repository
>   is readily available to everyone via a network share, this is a bad
>   idea. It removes any layers of protection between the users and the
>   repository: users can accidentally (or intentionally) corrupt the
>   repository database, it becomes hard to take the repository offline
>   for inspection or upgrade, and it can lead to a mess of file
>   permission problems (see the [section called “Supporting Multiple
>   Repository Access Methods”](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html)). Note that this is also one of the reasons
>   we warn against accessing repositories via svn+ssh:// URLs—from a
>   security standpoint, it's effectively the same as local users
>   accessing via file://, and it can entail all the same problems if the
>   administrator isn't careful.

Read through the SO Q&A. There are number of people attesting to problems they ran into, doing it this way where the repository got corrupted.

Better to setup an actual `svnserve` daemon and let it control access to the repository. It's pretty simple to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up svnserve, and accessing the repo via svn:// or ssh+svn://

Alternatively, if you wish to keep using the file:// method, make sure both you and your friend are in the same group, and set the repo directory to use the set group permission

```
usermod -a -G <group> <user>
chgrp <group> /path/to/repo
chmod 2770 /path/to/repo
```

this will ensure that any new files created will inherit group permissions, and should help alleviate filesystem permission issues.

Comment: For setting it up I used this tutorial: http://www.howtoforge.com/debian_subversion_websvn and I am accessing the repo using svn+ssh:// . I can't tell if I am using svnserve, I don't remember such thing.

Comment: From what I read online, it seems I am already using svnserve.